# How to tell if an element is in a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Let $G=<a>$ be a cyclic group. $O(a)=24$. We will define $H_k$: $H_k=<a^k>$. Find for what $k$ values, $0\leq k \leq 23$, $a^5H_k=a^{13}H_k$.

I couldn't figure a way to answer this quickly. I know that $a^5H_k=a^{13}H_k \iff a^5\in a^{13}H_k$.

Obviously it will be equal for all $k$ such that $gcd(k,24)=1$. It will also be equal if $k|16$. Beyond that I am unable to tell (without checking all values one by one...). Is there an efficient way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $a^5H_k = a^{13}H_k$ if and only if $a^8\in H_k = \langle a^k\rangle$.

Comment: I saw this too, but again, how can I tell if $a^8$ is in $H_k$?

Comment: $km \equiv 8\pmod{24}$ if and only if $km\equiv 0\pmod 8$ and $km\equiv 2\pmod 3$. We should ensure that there exists an integer $m$ such that the equation holds. The first equation cannot tell anything, but the second implies that $3\nmid k$.

Comment: Alright, and how is it possible to show that if 3 doesn't divide k then $a^8$ is in $H_k$. This is supposed to be an if and only if statement.

Comment: Discuss the remainder. If $k\equiv 1\pmod3$ then choose $m = 8$, and if $k\equiv 2\pmod 3$ then choose $m = 16$.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted, your question is equivalent to finding solutions to

$$nk \equiv 16\pmod{16}$$

since $a^5\in a^{13}H_k$ means $a^{8+nk} = a^0$. [In general](https://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0702/0702488.pdf), an equation

$$a_1x_1 + \dots a_nx_n\equiv b\pmod{m}$$

has solutions if and only if $\gcd(a_1,\dots, a_n, m)~|~b$. Thus, the equation $nk\equiv 16\pmod{24}$ has solutions for $n$ when $\gcd(k,24)~|~16$. Since $24 = 2^3\cdot3$, the only obstruction to $k$ being a viable option is if $k\equiv 0\pmod{3}$. Thus, the only $k$ that do not work are

$$3,6,9,12,15,18,21.$$

---

As a general statement, let $G=\langle a\rangle$ where $|a| = m$. If we want to find the $k$ such that $a^sH_k = a^tH_k$, we're really solving the equation

$$nk \equiv s-t\pmod{m}$$

which has a solution for $n$ when $\gcd(k,m)~|~(s-t)$.

Comment: I was able to reach that myself, however I don't know how to solve this efficiently (without checking values for each $k$).

Comment: @איתןלוי I missed a few cases. Hopefully the edited answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: We were not taught to solve those kind of equations to that level, which makes me believe there is a different way.